# Registering a shutdown hook in Spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application which is not calling bean destroy methods on shutdown. I've seen references to this being due to instantiation in a beanRefFactory, and that this can be circumvented through manually calling registerShutdownHook() on an the application context.This method seems to have disappeared from spring between versions 2.0 - 2.5.

Can someone point me in the direction of how this is now done?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a link to the description of the initial problem that you described?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This method is still available in [`ConfigurableApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook()) and implemented by [`AbstractApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook()).

So you might be able to do this

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ...;
if (ctx instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).registerShutdownHook();
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply call `((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).close()` yourself while closing down the application or using your own shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run(){
       if (ctx instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
           ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).close();
       }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So many upvotes, but the second statement is totally wrong, a `System.exit` in java would terminate the spring before ever getting to your shutdownhook, the right way to go are these 4 ways

1. InitializingBean and DisposableBean callback interfaces
2. Other Aware interfaces for specific behavior
3. custom init() and destroy() methods in bean configuration file
4. @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations

See [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/07/spring-bean-life-cycle/)!