# Spring scheduler shutdown error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

During development a SPRING based scheduler in a tomcat container, I always get this logoutput at undeploy webapp or shutdown server:

```
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
.
.
.    
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Prototype beans currently in creation]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Apr 28, 2010 4:21:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8606
```

How can I fix this?

thank you [stevedbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116880/stevedbrown)

I add this listener to my webapp

```
public class ShutDownHook implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        BeanFactory bf = (BeanFactory) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        if (bf instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)bf).close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

and my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>pkg.utility.spring.ShutDownHook</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but the error is still there.

spring config:

```
<bean id="run" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    <property name="targetObject" ref="scheduler" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="task" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrg" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="run" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrg" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: hey Alex, Have you got any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a shutdown hook - see [Registering a shutdown hook in Spring 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827212/registering-a-shutdown-hook-in-spring-2-5).

In your case, you probably should add a context listener to your webapp that does this (web.xml entry for the listener + implementing class).

Use close, it's easiest.

```
((YourClass)yourObject).close();
```

Comment: I add the listener but nothing happends.

Comment: You want ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)bf).close();, not ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)bf).registerShutdownHook(); unless you actually want to register the shutdown hook with your runtime [good for junit] (Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run(){
       if (ctx instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
           ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).close();
       }
    }
 });
)

Comment: I'm blind which object I have to close, I added the spring configuration and altered my listener class.

Answer (score 6):

Imho this is an issue of the quartz scheduler. I filed a bug https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-192. As a workaround the sleep() solution suggested by Colin Peters works for me. 
To not trigger the shutdown twice one could also add the sleep to Spring's SchedulerFactoryBean:

```
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;

public class SchedulerFactoryBeanWithShutdownDelay extends SchedulerFactoryBean{

  @Override
  public void destroy() throws SchedulerException {
    super.destroy();
    // TODO: Ugly workaround for https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-192
    try {
      Thread.sleep( 1000 );
    } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The quartz issue is fixed with Quartz 2.1. Unfortunately, Spring 3.1 is based on Quartz 1.8 and an update to 2.0 is considered for Spring 3.2 at the earliest. Source: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7987

Comment: Actually Spring 3.1 does support quartz 2.x http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/spring-3.1-rc1-release

Comment: I've upgraded to SpringFramework 4.1.6.RELEASE and Quartz 2.1.7 and still had to do this work around...

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution as none of the ones that I found online worked. This is specifically to shutdown the Quartz scheduler with Spring & Tomcat

My explanation is here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?34672-Quartz-doesn-t-shutdown&p=370060#post370060

Basically what the problem seemed to be is that Quartz doesn't have enough time to cleanly shutdown and the waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown argument doesn't seem to help. So I implemented a custom shutdown listener in the webapp, get a reference to the scheduler and shut it down manually. And then wait for 1 second before proceeding.

```
public class ShutDownHook implements ServletContextListener
{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get a reference to the Scheduler and shut it down
            WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
            Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) context.getBean("quartzSchedulerFactory");
            scheduler.shutdown(true);

            // Sleep for a bit so that we don't get any errors
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that threads are terminated, is to interrupt and join them.

This can by done by implementing [`org.quartz.InterruptableJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html), as described in the answer to the question [*How to prevent a memory leak in quartz [?]*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704418/how-to-prevent-a-memory-leak-in-quartz/15269920#15269920).